# How to reference an ID from another page as a variable in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, xml, include

So I've finally made some progress on my gallery site through a lot of help from everyone here, so thanks. Now I have one last, hopefully very easy question. To begin, here's the scenario:

Since I'm new to Javascript I'm trying to learn javascript BRFORE I delve into jquery so I'm trying to do everything in (I believe the term is) vanilla javascript. Without going into all the code, I've made a gallery for my artwork that has a thumb slider at the top of the page and a field where the selected artwork (including additional views, description, title, etc) will display. Rather than take on multi arrays right now I've built a page called 'gallery/php' that house all of the prebuilt divs that will be called into the field (titled 'generic'). Using innerHTML, I am making a simple call so that when the desired thumbnail is selected it calls the corresponding div by id and writes it in place of the 'generic' div.

Simple enough...

The problem is that I have about 40 of these and if I do a php include and hide the include in a hidden div while the artwork doesn't display it takes FOREVER to load the page and this seems like a very bad idea. What I would like to do is modify the function I am using right now so that instead of calling the id on the current page it will know which external page to reference and which div (based on id) to pull and populate the 'generic' div with. The script currently looks like this:

```
function changeDiv(art) {
        viewer = document.getElementById('generic'),
        targetInfo = document.getElementById(art);
        viewer.innerHTML = targetInfo.innerHTML; 
}
```

What I would like to do is (disregarding syntax):

```
function changeDiv(art) {
    viewer = document.getElementById('generic'),
    targetInfo = ***src = gallery.php, #(art);***
    viewer.innerHTML = targetInfo.innerHTML; 
}
```

The only thing I've seen that is similar to what I want to do is .load() in jquery but I don't know how to translate that back to javascript.

Comment: There isn't any javascript equivalent, you have to  use plain javascript ajax or jquery's ajax or load function to do that

Comment: Thanks Sabin - any thoughts as to what the javascript I'd want to use would be?

Comment: You can use jquery. THis can be done with few lines of code using jquery.

Comment: You'd need an ajax call to your PHP script. Then you'd have to traverse the script output to find your targetInfo and set the variable via the return value of that

Comment: Thanks Sabin. I'm trying to avoid jquery at the moment, just because I want to understand the fundamentals first, but I'll be moving to jquery eventually.

Christopher, I'm really a novice at this... would you have any examples of this, or maybe a tutorials you could point me towards?

Comment: It would be good to know how your php script is set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! Here goes my attempt. Please note that while this should probably be vetted through an AJAX library (like jQuery), that's not what the OP asked for.

**Also, I didn't know the gallery.php set up so I went for my best attempt.

**Also I know that this is horrible and has no validation or anything else good about it, but this is more of a proof of concept. (Tracer code for those Pragmatic Programmers)

Assuming you have a gallery.php set up as the following:

```
<?php
    $pull = $_GET["pull"];
    $gallery[0] = "<div>Your art work img tags here</div>";
    $gallery[1] = "<div>Some more art work</div>";
    //Pull from the changeDiv parameter in the JavaScript below.
    echo $gallery[$pull];
?>
```

We'll go with some JavaScript like the following:

```
var changeDiv = function(pull) {
    //Pull parameter indicates an array 
    //index within the gallery.php $gallery array

    var ajaxObj;

    //Our AJAX objet shall be declared
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        ajaxObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        ajaxObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    //When the ajaxObj changes it's ready 
    //state, do this stuff below
    ajaxObj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //But only if the ready state is 
        //really ready and the status is good to go
        if(ajaxObj.readyState==4 && ajaxObj.status==200) {
            var response = this.responseText;
            document.getElementById("viewer").innerHTML=response;
        }
    }
    //Open the async connection to 
    //gallery.php and send your GET 
    //global (pull)
    ajaxObj.open("GET","gallery.php?pull="+pull,true);

    //Send it and pray
    ajaxObj.send();
}
```

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/16/50-excellent-ajax-tutorials/ - Some tutorial listings for AJAX

Comment: Thanks Christopher - this is well beyond my understanding but I think I get the general idea. Now in the php portion at the top. is that how the gallery.php page is supposed to be built or is that the include I add to my digital-artwork.php page?

Comment: Thanks - and to be honest, I'm still trying to figure out how to 'accept' answers. It keeps telling me I can't upvote(?) until I'm at 15 if I'm reading it correctly